# Need help in using SPEL in Annotation Value?

Tags: lambda, spring-annotations, spring-el, spring-kafka

Tried below SPEL expression, but it fails to work. Need help!

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{Arrays.asList(${kafka.topic.helloworld}.split(',')).stream().map(p -> p+envSuffix).toArray(String[]::new)}")
```

Comment: In future, you MUST provide more information than "fails to work"; you should provide the error message and stack trace. However, your problems are obvious this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is: One of the way to add lambda into annotation is as follows:
 In the KafkaReceiver class's method -

```
@Autowired
  TopicUtil                      topicUtil;


  @KafkaListener(topics = "#{topicUtil.suffixTopics()}")


  //In the TopicUtil - add the follwoing method

  public String[] suffixTopics() {
      return Arrays.asList(pTopics.split(",")).stream().map(p -> p + envSuffix).toArray(String[]::new);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I see that `${kafka.topic.helloworld}` has to be wrapped to the `''`, just because property-placeholder works first and then SpEL will treat the result a an active variable. For example you have there, `foo,bar,baz`. How does it look in Java? Nothing more than wrong code. But when it is `"foo,bar,baz"`, the language knows that it is a String. The same with SpEL - it must be like `'${kafka.topic.helloworld}'`.

But that's not all. I'm afraid SpEL doesn't support lambdas. I suggest you to have some utility bean, which you could call from this expression like:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myUtility.parseTopics('${kafka.topic.helloworld}')")
```

And all that hard conversion logic will be done in the `parseTopics()` utility Java method.

There is a Collection [Projection feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection) in SpEL, but you still would need to do arrays manipulations here and there.

Comment: Right - SpEL is NOT JAVA - it's the Spring Expression __Language__; it doesn't have Lambdas; however, you __can__ register lambdas as SpEL Functions; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840190/spring-expression-language-java-8-foreach-or-stream-on-list/48842973#48842973).

Comment: + even if lambda were supported access to static method of Arrays should be written `T(java.util.Arrays).asList...`

Answer (score -2):

@Tuneit You can set the kafka topics directly like this it.
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.helloworld}")

application.properties
kafka.topic.helloworld=