# Implement a function over an array nested inside an Hashmap to perform aggregate operation using SpEL Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a payload like

```
String payload = "{\"array\":[{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":10},{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":20},{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":30}],\"boolean\":true,\"color\":\"gold\",\"null\":null,\"number\":123,\"object\":{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"},\"string\":\"HelloWorld\"}";
```

This string payload is mapped as a HashMap using

```
Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, HashMap.class);
```

Now, I want to add a functionality that enables me to get value and perform some operations using just a `String Expression` passed.

For Eg:

1. `doSomething(data, "data.array")` // Output : `[{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":10},{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":20},{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":30}]` -> as an Object
2. `doSomething(data, "data.array.stream().map(item -> item.get('c')).sum()")` // Output : `10 + 20 + 30 = 60`

I want to achieve something like this.
Can someone pls help, how can I implement this.

Answer (score 1):

SpEL cannot understand lambda expressions (->).

You can use streams but **without lambdas**.

follow this answer for a detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842973/7972621

Answer (score 0):

`SPeL` cannot understand lambda expressions (->), but there is an implicit method.

You can register and use lambdas as [`SPeL` #functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842973/2039546).

You can extend `SPeL` by registering user defined functions that can be called within the expression string. The function is registered with the `StandardEvaluationContext` using the method.

We can write an example that takes the `SPeL` code directly or contains the `StandardEvaluationContext`:

```java
public class SPeLExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // JSON payload.
            String payload = "...";

            // Response 1 test.
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> response1 = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>)
                    doSomething(payload, "#root['array']");
            System.out.println("Response 1 => " + response1);

            // Response 2 test.
            StandardEvaluationContext standardEvaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
            standardEvaluationContext.registerFunction("getMapItem",
                    SPeLExample.class.getMethod("getMapItem", String.class));
            standardEvaluationContext.registerFunction("toInteger",
                    SPeLExample.class.getMethod("toInteger"));
            Integer response2 = (Integer) doSomething(payload,
                    "#root['array'] == null ? null " +
                            ": #root['array'].stream()" +
                            "   .map(#getMapItem('c'))" +
                            "   .mapToInt(#toInteger()).sum()",
                    standardEvaluationContext);
            System.out.println("Response => " + response2);
        } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    }

    public static Object doSomething(String payload,
                                     String expressionString) {
        return doSomething(payload, expressionString, null);
    }

    public static Object doSomething(String payload, 
                                     String expressionString, 
                                     StandardEvaluationContext standardEvaluationContext) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(payload, HashMap.class);
            ExpressionParser expressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
            Expression expression = expressionParser.parseExpression(expressionString);
            if (standardEvaluationContext == null)
                return expression.getValue(map);
            return expression.getValue(standardEvaluationContext, map);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Function<LinkedHashMap, Object> getMapItem(String key) {
        return o -> o.get(key);
    }

    public static ToIntFunction<Object> toInteger() {
        return o -> Integer.valueOf((int)o);
    }
}
```

I added two lambda functions `getMapItem` and `toInteger`, I registered them in [`StandardEvaluationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/spel/support/StandardEvaluationContext.html).

I rewrote your `"data.array.stream().map(item -> item.get('c')).sum()"` code to handle special functions like this:

```java
"#root['array'] == null ? null : #root['array'].stream().map(#getMapItem('c')).mapToInt(#toInteger()).sum()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Library *Josson* has the capability to get value and perform some operations using just a `String Expression` passed.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
String payload = "{\"array\":[{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":10},{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":20},{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":30}],\"boolean\":true,\"color\":\"gold\",\"null\":null,\"number\":123,\"object\":{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"},\"string\":\"HelloWorld\"}";
Josson data = Josson.fromJsonString(payload);
```

Query an array node

```
JsonNode node = data.getNode("array");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ {
  "a" : "b",
  "c" : 10
}, {
  "a" : "b",
  "c" : 20
}, {
  "a" : "b",
  "c" : 30
} ]
```

Evaluate data by a function

```
JsonNode node = data.getNode("array.c.sum()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
60.0
```