# java Spel with stream API

Tags: java, spring-el, spring-expression-language

I have this string `1|1|1|1` and I want to sum the numbers inside spel statement.
I tried this one but got wrong expression.

```
T(java.util.Arrays).stream(SERVICE_CLASS.split('|')).reduce(Integer::sum)
```

the log :

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression [new Object[] {T(java.util.Arrays).stream(SERVICE_CLASS.split('|')).reduce(Integer::sum)}] @81: EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but was 'colon(:)'
```

the full code :

```
 @Test fun `test sum values`() {
    val cont = ScriptingContext.default();

    val contextrecord: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
        "value" to "1|1|1|1"
    )


    val context = cont.getEvalContext()
    context.setRootObject(contextrecord)
    val value = cont.parser.parseExpression("new Object[] {T(java.util.Arrays).stream(value.split('|')).reduce(Integer::sum)}").getValue(context) as Array<Object>
    println(value.toString())
    assertEquals(value[0], "4")
}
```

any suggest to do it ?

Comment: *I tried this one but got wrong expression.* Please share the exact message

Comment: sorry, I will update the question

Comment: By the way, that errors means you're not sharing the full expression. Please include a [example].

Comment: I shared the full unit test function

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring-el, but are you absolutely positive it supports method references? Because I can't find anything about them in the documentation, and the text of the error implies it doesn't like `Integer::sum`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca this is my question
what should I do to sum this numbers

Comment: SpEL stands for Spring Expression **LANGUAGE**. It is not Java; no lambdas, or method references are supported.

Answer (score 1):

SpEL stands for Spring Expression **LANGUAGE**. It is not Java; no lambdas, or method references are supported.

You can, however, register lambdas as SpEL functions; see [Spring Expression Language - Java 8 forEach or stream on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840190/spring-expression-language-java-8-foreach-or-stream-on-list/48842973#48842973)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the requirement said we need to do it without any additional methods. do you have any trick to do it ?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. The SpEL was designed mostly for simple properties access and it is significantly slow because it uses a reflection to call all those methods. What you trying to do (no additional methods) is an abuse of SpEL capabilities. Consider to use a scripting feature in Spring Integration instead: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/scripting.html#scripting